# Rails 5 tries to save the empty string as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am in the process of upgrading my Rails app from version 4.1.16 to 5.2.3

I have a column with not null constraint and default value as 0

**schema.rb:**

```
t.integer wait_time_minutes  default: 0, null: false
```

The relevant form contains the following:

```
 = f.select :wait_time_minutes, [15, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120], { include_blank: true }, class: 'form-control'
```

While submitting this form without selecting any values, the following is submitted in the params:

```
"wait_time_minutes"=>""
```

And it tries to update the column with the nil:

```
UPDATE "table_name" SET "wait_time_minutes" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "table_name"."id" = $3  ["wait_time_minutes", nil], ["updated_at", "2019-06-23 05:32:28.368640"], ["id", 1445]]
```

Since the column has not null constraint, it raises the following exception:

```
PG::NotNullViolation - ERROR:  null value in column "wait_time_minutes" violates not-null constraint
```

But it wasn't the way it was working before. It worked fine in Rails 4.1.16.

How can I fix this issue? I do have this issue in most of the places of my application. Thanks.

Comment: i think, its normal. no value passed string given, database expects integer but yr trying to save string. `null: false` returns nil.

Comment: As @7urkm3n said, this is normal because browser send an empty string. One solution would be to replace the include_blank with a real 0 value.

Comment: @7urkm3n Do you have any idea about why it was working on Rails 4.1.16?

Comment: @colinux with `{ include_blank: '0' }`, It will show the same error since the include_blank will set the option content as '0'. It won't set value for the option element. So it will submit an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to use [`before_save`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

```
# model.rb
before_save do
  self.wait_time_minutes ||= 0
end
```

If you're not familiar with `||=` it's common Ruby trick to instantiate a variable if it's not already set.